# Automating password change inside a Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, automation, passwords

I need to use a bash script:

1. Launch the container
2. Generate a password
3. Enter the container
4. Run the 'cd /' command
5. Change the password using htpasswd to the generated one

I tried it like this:

```
docker restart c1
a = date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash 'echo cd /'
htpasswd user.passwd webdav a
```

And so:

```
docker restart c1
docker exec -u 0 -it c1 bash
cd /
a = date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
htpasswd user.passwd webdav a
```

With the first option , I get:

> bash: echo cd /: No such file or directory

With the second one, it enters the container and does nothing

I will be grateful for any help

I tried many variations of the script, which did not help me

Comment: => `a=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32); docker exec -u 0 --workdir=/ c1 htpasswd -b user.password webdav $a`. This takes for granted that a `user.password` file already exists (else you need to add the `-c` option as well to `htpasswd`). Note that this looks like a total anti-pattern and is probably the sign you're in an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). You probably want to do all of this in a dockerfile, not inside a running container.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Docker or debugging tools like `docker exec` just to generate an htpasswd file.

[htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) is part of the Apache distribution, and you should be able to install it on your host system using your OS package manager.  Since it just manipulates a credential file it doesn't need the actual server.

```bash
# On the host system, without using Docker at all
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install apache2-utils

# Make sure to wrap the password-generating command in `$()`
a=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32)

# Make sure to use a variable reference `$a`
htpasswd user.passwd webdav "$a"
```

This gives you a `user.passwd` file on your local system.  Now when you launch your container, you can bind-mount the file into the container:

```bash
docker run -d -p 80:80 ... \
  -v "$PWD/user.passwd:/usr/local/apache2/conf/user.passwd" \
  httpd
```

The container will be immediately ready to use.  If you delete and recreate this container, you do not need to repeat the manual setup step.  If you need to launch multiple copies of the container, they can all have the same credentials file without doing manual steps.